# fail to build as I use react-flatpickr

Tags: reactjs, build, flatpickr

I get error when I using react-flatpickr, error return:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

here is my code

```
import Flatpickr from "react-flatpickr";

const CourseList= (props) => {

...

return(
 <>
  ...
  <Flatpickr />
  ...
 </>
)

}

export default CourseList;
```

if anyone have experienced the same problem and have found a solution or have other alternative ways, please help me to solve this problem. Many thanks!!

I've tried to change:

```
import Flatpickr from "react-flatpickr";
```

to

```
import { Flatpickr } from "react-flatpickr";
```

but not working.

Comment: What is new `Date().fp_incr(0)`?  Also did you maybe forget a return statement?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! fp_incr(0) is flatpickr function. I added a return statement in the post now. I have tried to delete all props for <Flatpickr /> and get same error. Also I success to build when I delete <Flatpickr /> component. The issue seems related to <Flatpickr />, but I didn't find the way to solve it....

Comment: What does it return when you console.log(Flatpickr)?